# Refreshing page without refreshing form

Tags: jquery, forms

Here is my code on the main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable(){
    $('#tableHolder').load('table2.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable, 500);
    });
}
</script>
```

This loads table2.php onto this page and refreshes it/ Now in table2.php there is a form. I want this to stop refreshing when someone starts typing in the form. If it keeps refreshing it will just refresh the form and everything in the form will be lost. I was thinking jquery or JavaScript but couldn't find anything on how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: dude, you're already using jquery... what did you try by the way?

Comment: What do you mean? I haven't tried anything

Comment: so put an onkeydown on the form, and delete your timeout once a key is pressed.

Comment: it's a shame, you should... we can help you correcting issues where you're stuck, but don't expect us to write the code for you... unless you get lucky and somebody has the time / is devoted enough for your question only to do it all for you...

Comment: "I haven't tried anything" You're not going to get a lot of answers unless you show some effort.

Comment: I thought of something like that, but since the form is on a different page, I didn't know how to

Comment: I have tried a lot of things and a bunch of Google searches. And nothing has worked. So I came here to ask if someone knew how to do it

Comment: Earlier you said you didn't try anything. Which is it? If you "tried a  lot of things", show what you tried and explain in what why they didn't work.

Comment: I tried doing a onkeypress event on the form page but I couldn't figure out how to change the reload time on this page with it

Answer (score 0):

```
add some variable boolean on the top of script

<script type="text/javascript">
var isFormUse = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){

 refreshTable(isFormUse);

//then declare some form inputs here
$('#textbox').on('focus', function(){
 isFormUse = 1
});
});

function refreshTable(isFormUse){
 if (isFormUse == 0) { 
    $('#tableHolder').load('table2.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable, 500);
    });
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can improove this adding: `$('#textbox').on('blur', function(){
 isFormUse = 0
});
});`

Comment: The problem is that #textbox is on the page table2.php I also want table2.php to still stay there, just not refresh when the key is pressed in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var reloadData = 0; // store time
    refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable() {
    $('#tableHolder').load('table2.php', function() {
        if (reloadData != 0)
            window.clearTimeout(reloadData);
        reloadData = window.setTimeout(refreshTable, 2000);
    }); 
}
```

#### HTML & PHP

```
<div id="tableHolder">

<div>
```

#### table2.php

```
<table>
    <tr>
          .....
    </tr>
     .....
</table>
```

#### Result

```
<div id="tableHolder">
  <table>
    <tr>
          .....
    </tr>
     .....
  </table>
<div>
```

Comment: Sorry this is not what I want. The form is on table2.php, not this page

Comment: I have two pages, main.php and table2.php . On main.php table2.php gets loaded and refreshed using JavaScript. The form is on table2.php I want when the form is being typed into that table2.php is no longer refreshed BUT still stays loaded

Comment: table2.php remove oepning and closing `<table>` element. to solve this issue.another option i update my answer.

Comment: This code works, except that it doesn't refresh it when I HAVE NOT typed into the form that is in the table